# Javascript's String.slice() input values

Tags: javascript, string, slice

Can I portably use this to slice off the end of a string, too?

`"01abc23".slice(2,-2)` produces `"abc"` on Safari. I have not found negative input values documented. But I'd prefer to use them because it means I can skip declaring the string as a variable!

Because otherwise I'd need

```
var x = "01abc23"; x.slice(2,x.length-2)
```

Comment: It's documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Comment: Ah, strange. That spells it out couldn't be more clearly. Not sure which MDN page I found but it was a different one.

Comment: Yes! It works and is standard, except on IE3 and earlier, IIRC. But I hope you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to transcribe these into answers so I can accept.